# Distributing bordered padded figures with flexbox so images are equal height

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, figure

I'm using jquery to set the flex-grow value of a wrapper div to a figure's image's aspect ratio.  This is based on a suggestion [here](https://codepen.io/blimpage/pen/obWdgp).

But when I add a border and padding to the figure, the images are no longer the same height.  Is there a way to include the border and padding in this calculation to get all the images to be the same height? Or another way to get these figure images to have the same height?

This becomes obvious if you comment out the border and padding from the figure css, then all the figure images become equal height.

EDIT: I just realized this has completely different behaviour in Chrome.  It's almost fine in Firefox, but in Chrome the images are completely different sizes!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.pack').css({
      "display": "flex"
    })
    .children().each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "width": "100%"
      });
      var $img = $(this).find('img');
      var aspect = $img[0].naturalWidth / $img[0].naturalHeight;
      $(this).wrap('<div style="display:flex; flex: 0% ' + aspect + ' 1;" />')
      $img.css({
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "auto"
      })
    });
});
```

```css
figure {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin: 0;
}

div.pack>div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='pack'>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Big cap tion Caption here Big cap tion Capt ion here </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x500">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're adding another wrapper to it. Don't wrap the figures in `<div>`s and it will work as expected.

But it won't work on very small devices, because the captions will be too tall, from wrapping. I suggest you use a `@media` query to display them full width on mobiles. Because you're hard-coding `style` attributes to them, you'll need `!important` to apply your `@media` query `flex`.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('div.pack').children().each(function() {
    let img = $(this).find('img')[0], 
        asp = img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight;
    $(this).css({
      flex: asp + ''
    })
  });
});
```

```css
figure {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  font: italic normal 14px/normal serif;
}

div.pack>figure:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.pack {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
  .pack {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .pack figure:not(#duh) {
    flex: 1 0 auto !important;
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='pack'>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
    <figcaption>Big cap tion Caption here Big cap tion Capt ion here </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x500">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150">
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

---

**Side note:** I really don't understand why `flex: 0% x 1;` which gets parsed into:

```
flex-grow: 0%;
flex-shrink: x;
flex-basis: 1;
```

works the same as `flex: x;`,  which gets properly parsed into:

```
flex-grow: x;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

but I'm not expecting it to work cross-browser/cross-device, so i just reverted it to its original form.

I also moved the entire script from `document.ready` to `window.load` event, as you really don't want it to run before `<img>`s have loaded.

---

And, as final note, using Firefox in frontend development has (at least) two major downsides:

- its development tools have been consistently with a few months behind Chrome for the past years
- it has a smaller market share than Chrome - which means you're developing for less than 15% of your users and later on, in cross-browser phase you might have to apply fixes for more than 60% of your users. Makes more sense to do it the other way around.

Comment: The thoughts on developing in Chrome were helpful too, thanks for that addition.